# How to have the bot send a message every time a user with a specific role speaks in any channel | Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have the bot send a message everytime someone with the Bullied role speaks. I would also like to have it mention the user in that response message but that is, of course, optional. I'm somewhat new to discord.py but still know quite a few things.

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
@commands.has_role('Bullied')
async def on_message(ctx, message):
  if message.content != "":
    if y == 0 or y2 == 0 or y3 == 0:
      await ctx.send("hi")
```

Here is the error message I receive every time someone speaks in the server:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an event using `@commands.has_role()` will not work. You could do a check if a specific role is in member roles. Here is an example.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:  # skip bot messages
        return

    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name='Bullied') # get the role using name
    member = message.guild.get_member(message.author.id) # get the member in the guild
    if role in member.roles:
        #code here
        channel = bot.get_channel(123) # wanted channel to notify
        await channel.send(f'Hey there {message.author.name}')
```

Comment: `guild = bot.get_guild(message.guild.id)` is really an unnecessary line, since `guild = message.guild` is enough to obtain the `discord.Guild` object

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, `on_message` only accepts `message` as a positional argument, you provided it with two, i.e `message` and `ctx`

here `ctx` is not acting as `context` but `message` instead, and then you provided an extra argument `message`  which it doesn't know about [because `ctx` is acting as `discord.Message` object]

```
@client.event
@commands.has_role('Bullied')
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author.bot:
       return
  if message.content != "":
    if y == 0 or y2 == 0 or y3 == 0: #what is this? I am not sure what y, y2, and y3 are (if not defined, would raise UnboundLocalError, local variable 'y' referenced before assignment) 
      await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} hi")
```

Comment: This works, although the @commands.has_role('Bullied') isn't working as intended. It appears to ignore whether the user has the role or not, would you happen to have a fix?

Comment: the role name needs to be exactly same as the name you have entered (case sensitive) otherwise it won't work

Comment: `commands.has_role` only works for commands not events

Comment: ahhhh totally forgot about that, that's right